# I'm trying to add a CheckboxListTile but the value of the checkbox doesn't updates

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm trying to add a CheckboxListTile but the value of tha checkbox doesn't updates it always stays false, what can i do? need help, here is the code a have. im working with flutter

```
class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  bool isChecked1 = true;
  TextEditingController controlNombre = TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController controlMail = TextEditingController();

  GlobalKey<FormState> keyForm = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xffff0082),
          shadowColor: Colors.white,
          title: const Text('Captura de Información'),
        ),`
        body:Form(
          key: keyForm,
          child: ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 40.0, 20.0, 10.0),
              children: [
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    TextFieldServices(
                      'Ingrese Nombre Completo',
                      controlNombre,
                      validateText: ValidateText.nombre,
                    ),
                    CheckboxListTile(
                      title: const Text(
                        'Acepto Términos y Condiciones',
                      ),
                      autofocus: false,
                      activeColor: const Color(0xffff0082),
                      checkColor: Colors.white,
                      selected: isChecked1,
                      value: isChecked1,
                      onChanged: (bool? value) {
                        setState(() {
                          isChecked1 = value ?? false;
                        });
                      },
                      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                      tristate: true,
                    ),
                  ]
                 ],
                ),
              ]),
            ));
           }
          }
```

I already have a variable `bool isChecked1 = false;` i also noticed that if i change the value of the isChecked to true, now the checkbox always stays true.

I need the checkbox to change to true, also it doesn't get colored when it's selected.

Comment: can you include where you've define `isChecked1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure define `isChecked1` outside the build method.

```dart
  bool isChecked1 = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Comment: it´s outside the build method

Comment: can you include  full sample snippet

Comment: okay i´ve just add the sample above in the question.

Comment: seems ok to me, try to rebuild the app

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a boolean variable outside this code, eg. after declaring your class. Create a function that receives a boolean argument and manipulate your external variable inside your function. Also, use this boolen variable in all places that needs changes in state based on your boolean variable.
I hope it helps you.